# Filter searchText to tableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

Right now I am using following

```
let data = ["New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA" . . .]

var filteredData: [String]!

filteredData = data
```

But I want to use Firebase, with an almost identical structure, by using this

```
var data = [Categories]()
```

(This is `categories`)

```
struct Categories {

let key:String!
let content:String!
let itemRef:FIRDatabaseReference?

init (content:String, key:String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.content = content
    self.itemRef = nil
}

init (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    itemRef = snapshot.ref

    if let CategoriesContent = snapshot.value!["content"] as? String {
        content = CategoriesContent
    } else {
        content = ""
    }
}
```

}

So that when I search for something these lines is supposed to filter out everything that aren't correct

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    // Unhide tableview, this will be changed to another method
    tableView.hidden = false

    filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter({(dataString: String) -> Bool in
        // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
        return dataString.rangeOfString(searchText) != nil
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

But since `filter({(dataString: String)` only takes strings it does not work

**Question** : Is there any other way to replace the string with my Firebase struct?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) is so clear in UISearchResultsUpdating and Filtering section.

Comment: Can you please provide some info about tutorial? In case that link is removed answer will be useless!

Comment: @Victor: 'cause you didn't post all class that contains UISearchController code. Please review UISearchResultUpdating , UISearchBarDelegate. Hope you give more detail for discussion.